# JCarousel wrap set to 'circular' bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jcarousel

I'm trying to set up a JCarousel instance with the wrap set to circular, however, I noticed an issue where I "inspect element" in Chrome, duplicate `<li>` elements are added to the html when the slides repeat (it can be viewed on the official example page).

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_circular.html

I know this is an open bug on GitHub. I'm just wondering if anyone has found a temporary workaround.

Comment: It appears the script produces more elements in the dom each time it changes. Is there a reason you can't use a better carousel plugin?

Answer (score 2):

i solve it with giving the li items explicit width and height in the css

```
.jcarousel-item {width:200px;height:200px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same bug before, and didn't see any helpful comments, so I thought I'd suggest a "better" plugin. Try [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I won infinite duplicating `<li>`
Just add style

```
.jcarousel-clip {width:198px; height:130px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the **jcarousellite** script file change the    circular: true, to false or
add this parameter to your script as below

$(".class").jCarouselLite({circular: false});