# JCarousel Center slide, circular wrap issue

Tags: jquery, slide, jcarousel

Created a slider with Wrap = circular and center = true,

Left is always blank. I tried editing the source to prepend last few siblings to the first but didn't work. How do I get seemless left/right scroll with active center slide

http://jsfiddle.net/AYBJ6/4/

```
$('.jcarousel')
     .jcarousel({

     wrap: 'circular',
     center: true
 });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JCarousel wrap set to 'circular' bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890955/jcarousel-wrap-set-to-circular-bug)

Comment: Not a duplicate as the questions are different. This question is trying to fix the white space before the slider. The one you linked to talks about adding more list items. And if anyone has found an answer to this question please share.